# Is it possible send and receive messages from aws sqs using a service rabbitMQ producer/consumer?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, amazon-sqs

I recently started to learn about RabbitMQ.
I created two micro-services with spring boot, a producer and a consumer that are running locally sending and receiving messages from my localhost server (container) rabbitmq, but I was thinking of using my aws account to send and receive messages to an aws sqs queue.
It's possible? how could i be doing this?

i expect to find some documentation or good examples.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon SQS is not RabbitMQ.

You can use Amazons SQS' SDK in Javascript, you can not connect those directly.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sqs-examples.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sqs-examples-send-receive-messages.html